# Freestyle Uniform Displacement

Tags: rendering, modifiers, geometry, freestyle

I been looking online for this so idk if this is a duplicate or not, I never seen this asked before.

But for the curvy lines I went with the Sinus Displacement modifier in the geometry tab and its all spikey, I'm trying to smooth it but I have no clue what modifier to use for that.

---

But the bigger problem of the two is show below with the first picture zoomed out and the second picture Zoomed in.

I'm wanting the curves to be uniform but as you can see when zoomed out its less curvy and when zoomed in its more curvy. Is there any way how to set a uniform amount of curves to the sinus displacement?

***Out***:
[image: Zoomed Out]

***In***:
[image: Zoomed In]

---

***-please feel free to edit the question if you think it could be improved in someway, I don't really know how to make the question/post look better***

Comment: Freestyle works on the rendered image, by zooming in the 3d view you give it a different image to work with. Render the scene and adjust the settings to suit that image.

Comment: @sambler thanks :D but is there a way to make this process automatic? Like a ik freestyle setup, or just self updating. Or should I just learn code for that?

Answer (score 1):

Basically, you want to increase the Wavelength and Amplitude of the Sinus when the camera go closer to the object. You can do that with Drivers.

On the picture below, you can see the settings for the Wavelength driver :

- a variable (named *dist*) return the distance between Cube and Camera
- we invert it (1/dist), cause we want the value to decrease when the distance increase
- we multiply it by a value (*200), which define the overall amplitude.

To find the right value, you can do trial and error, or calculate it. Here you can see *dist* is 10.439 ; say your desired Wavelength is 20 ; 1/10.439*x = 20 -> x = 20*10.439 = more or less 200.

The method is exactly the same for Amplitude. I used (1/dist)*30.

[image]